# Циклический сдвиг матрицы влево java

Tags: java, циклы, матрицы

Матрица сдвигается, но на место, куда должны передвинуться крайние столбцы, просто копируется крайний правый ряд на заданное кол-во сдвигов.

```
static void ShiftLeft(short arr[][], int position)
{
for (int k = 0; k < position; k++)
    for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        short temp = arr[i][arr[i].length-1];
        int j;
        for(j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j-1] = arr[i][j];
        }
        arr[i][j-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    short[][] m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    showMatrix(m);
    //shiftLeft(m, 5);
    shiftLeft2(m, 5);
    System.out.println();
    showMatrix(m);
}

// Вариант с пошаговым переставлением.
public static void shiftLeft(short[][] m, int steps) {
   for (int i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
     // количество реальных шагов, без лишних оборотов.
     // в условии не гарантируется одинаковое количество столбцов 
     // для всех строк, поэтому реальные шаги определяются для каждой строки
     int realSteps = steps % m[i].length;
     while(realSteps-- > 0) {
        short temp = m[i][0];
        for (int j=m[i].length-1; j>=0; j--) {
           short val = m[i][j];
           m[i][j] = temp;
           temp = val;        
        }
     }
   }
}
// Вариант с доп массивом. Быстрее, но затраты памяти на доп.массив
public static void shiftLeft2(short[][] m, int steps) {
   for (int i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
     int realSteps = steps % m[i].length;
     if(realSteps == 0) 
       continue;
     int rowLength = m[i].length;
     short[] temp = new short[rowLength]; 
     for (int j=0; j < rowLength; j++) {
        int newIndex = (j-realSteps<0) ? rowLength+j-realSteps : j-realSteps;
        temp[newIndex] = m[i][j];
     }
     for (int j=0; j<rowLength; j++ ) {       
       m[i][j] = temp[j];       
     }
   }
}


public static void showMatrix(short[][] m) {
   for (short[] s : m) {
      for (short k : s) {
         System.out.print(k + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }       
}
```

Результат

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

3 1 2 
6 4 5 
9 7 8
```