# Как выполнить сдвиг двумерного массива вниз?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Есть двумерный массив `NxN`, в котором необходимо выполнить циклический сдвиг вниз. Количество шагов сдвига нужно получать в качестве параметра. Я пытался разобрать метод из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568165/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-java), но на выходе получал тот же массив без сдвига.

В алгоритме по ссылке есть следующий фрагмент:

```
for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
    int newIndex = (j - realSteps < 0) ? rowLength + j - realSteps : j - realSteps;
    temp[newIndex] = m[i][j];
}
```

Мне не понятен момент с тернарными оператором. Буду благодарен, если кто-то сможет показать ещё какой-то вариант алгоритма.

Comment: Задача не сложная, просто не совсем понятно, как именно вы хотите сдвинуть массив. Приведите пример массива, шаг сдвига и ожидаемый результат. А тернарный оператор - штука простая. Представьте его в виде обычного условия if - else. То, что вы пишите в скобках if это выражение с левой стороны от вопросительного знака. С правой стороны вопросительного знака то, что вы бы записали в результирующей части if, а справой стороны двоеточия - в результирующей части else. Тернарный оператор является сокращенной записью обычного условного оператора if-else. Вот и все

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать ArrayList из одномерных массивов, ну и при циклическом сдвиге добавлять в лист последний элемент, затем удалять последний элемент.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
        };
        show(shift(matrix, 6));
    }

    private static int[][] shift(int[][] arr, int step) {
        int[] temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
            temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
            arr[0] = temp;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    private static void show(int[][] arr) {
        for (int[] anArr : arr) {
            for (int anAnArr : anArr) {
                System.out.print(anAnArr + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сдвигаем массив вниз на указанное число строк. Нижние строки добавляем наверх:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m1 = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    };

    int[][] m2 = shiftDown(m1, 1);

    Arrays.stream(m2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    // [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
```

```java
public static int[][] shiftDown(int[][] arr, int interval) {
    return Stream.concat(
            Arrays.stream(arr, arr.length - interval, arr.length),
            Arrays.stream(arr, 0, arr.length - interval))
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```